# ASP.net Coding User Roles into Login Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, authentication

I've developed a login page, which functions off of a stored procedure. The login part functions well, however, the website will consist of roles that will determine what page the user is directed to once they are logged into the secure section.  The columns I’m focusing on in the database / table are:
Guid        -0 column
Login_name  -9th column
Login_Pwd   -10th column
Role_ID         -11th column / Contains a value of 1 or a 2

**What I’m trying to do is:** get the login page to distinguish between the users with a Role_ID of 1 and those that have a Role_ID of 2. But, currently, when I log into the page, I’m directed to the SecurePage.aspx regardless of what Role ID the user has.  Could I please get some direction on this?

This is my **Stored Procedure**:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Check_Users]

       @Login_name as varchar(100),
       @Login_Pwd as varchar(50)
AS
       /* SET NOCOUNT ON */

       SELECT * FROM SupplierCompany WHERE Login_name=@Login_name AND Login_Pwd=@Login_Pwd 
RETURN
```

**This is the code behind my login button:**

```
Try
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
            con.Open()

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Check_Users", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            Dim p1 As New SqlParameter("Login_name", username.Text)
            Dim p2 As New SqlParameter("Login_Pwd", password.Text)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2)
            Dim rd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            If rd.HasRows Then
                rd.Read()
                lblinfo.Text = "You are Authorized."
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Text, True)
                Response.Redirect("securepages/SecurePage.aspx")
            Else
                lblinfo.Text = "Invalid username or password."
            End If

            'check the Role of the usre logging in
            While (rd.Read())
                Session("numrecord") = rd.GetValue(0).ToString()
                rd.GetValue(11).ToString()

                If rd.GetValue(11).ToString() = 1 Then
                    Response.Redirect("securepages/SecurePage.aspx")

                ElseIf rd.GetValue(11).ToString() = 2 Then
                    Response.Redirect("securepages/newShipment.aspx")

                End If
            End While

        Catch

        Finally
        End Try
```

..Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `If rd.HasRows Then` you redirect to the SecurePage, so I'm guessing it doesn't even reach the while. Try removing the `Response.Redirect("securepgaes/SecurePage.aspx")` inside this if, and adding the while loop there, like this:

```
If rd.HasRows Then
   rd.Read()
   lblinfo.Text = "You are Authorized."
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Text, True)
   'Response.Redirect("securepages/SecurePage.aspx") Remove this line

   'check the Role of the user logging in
   While (rd.Read())
      Session("numrecord") = rd.GetValue(0).ToString()
      rd.GetValue(11).ToString()

      If rd.GetValue(11).ToString() = 1 Then
         Response.Redirect("securepages/SecurePage.aspx")
      ElseIf rd.GetValue(11).ToString() = 2 Then
         Response.Redirect("securepages/newShipment.aspx")
      End If

   End While

Else
   lblinfo.Text = "Invalid username or password."
End If
```

Comment: Thank, I was able to figure it out, however, my remedy was similar to your suggestion. Thanks again

Comment: I'm curious now: what was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Where have you defined the code to redirect the logged in user?

The `Login` control by default will try and redirect you to a destination page once successful. I would think you should hook in to the `OnLoggedIn` event and redirect the page *before* the server has a chance to do it for you.

As an alternative if that doesn't work you could try building your own 'Login Control' - since you are using a stored procedure to validate users anyway, it's not a huge leap to dump a few textboxes on the page and go that way. At least then you don't need to worry about overriding the default behaviour. I believe ASP.NET provides a bunch of SPs you can use which will validate user passwords and such - check it out on the server (they are all like `dbo.aspnet_*`.